# osCommerce thinks table is missing, but it exists in database

Tags: php, database, oscommerce

When I try to log into the osCommerce admin, it shows the following error:

> 1146 - Table 'millakid_fbstore.TABLE_ADMINISTRATORS' doesn't exist
>   select id from TABLE_ADMINISTRATORS limit 1
>   [TEP STOP]

But the table already exists in the database. Why is this error coming up and what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Your table is not defined in the database_tables.php file.

Whenever you see osCommerce report that a database table doesn't exist, and the table name is in all caps with a `TABLE_` prefix, you should double-check database_tables.php (located in the relevant includes folder).

Here, you may be missing a line similar to this:

```
define('TABLE_ADMINISTRATORS', 'administrators');
```

In PHP, the convention is that variables written in all capital letters are constants that need to be, or have been, defined somewhere in the codebase.